# How to use brute-force process for optimization using R

Tags: r, optimization, time-series, filtering

I want to calculate the following formula in R.

[image]

where Kt is given by

[image]

The only unknown in this function is T. I want to optimize T using “brute-force” process within constrained dimension space of the parameter – typically 1 to 60.
I have tried to create a function like

```
library(hydroGOF)

expFilter <- function(W2, W1, T=1){
  K = 1
  W2 = W2(t-1) + K * (W1-W2(t-1))
  K = K / (K+exp(-1*gap/T))
}

Topt <- function(W1, W2, Tvals, objfunc=objfunc){
  objfunc = list(nse=NSE, rmse=rmse, bias=me, r=r)
  results = []
  for (n in 1:NROW(Tvals))
    Ttest = expFilter(W1, T=T)
    tempDf = cbind(Ttest, W2)
    names(tempDf) = c('simulation', 'observation')
    N = objectiveFunc(tempDf)
    results.append(N)
    
    # check to either find the min or max depending on objectivFunc
    if (objfunc %in% c('nse','r')) {
      best = max(results)
      objVal = max(results)
    }else {
      best = min(results)
      objVal = min(results)
    }
    out = list(T=Tvals[best], objval=objVal)
    return(out)
}
```

How to do this in R?

Here is the data

```
df = structure(list(Time = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17169, 17170, 
17171, 17172, 17173, 17174, 17175, 17176, 17177, 17178, 17179, 
17180, 17181, 17182, 17183, 17184, 17185, 17186, 17187, 17188, 
17189, 17190, 17191, 17192, 17193, 17194, 17195, 17196, 17197, 
17198, 17199, 17200, 17201, 17202, 17203, 17204, 17205, 17206, 
17207, 17208, 17209, 17210, 17211, 17212, 17213, 17214, 17215, 
17216, 17217, 17218, 17219, 17220, 17221, 17222, 17223, 17224, 
17225), class = "Date"), W1 = c(0.0260370901355039, 0.0242334551172363, 
0.0206261850807011, 0.0202793321925727, 0.0164177033714101, 0.0116773805669889, 
0.00823197521158028, 0.00397724645053882, 0.00115617629376129, 
0, 0.030869907043426, 0.0910373213707626, 0.128821162650881, 
0.157471211210285, 0.173727049900569, 0.15846552282292, 0.125052027933219, 
0.101188549229987, 0.0929334504925311, 0.0784349997687647, 0.0627341256994867, 
0.0581325440503168, 0.0917772741987698, 0.125560745502474, 0.148268047911946, 
0.143203995745271, 0.114785182444619, 0.0899273921287519, 0.0979743791333303, 
0.121375387319058, 0.361212597696897, 0.835591731027147, 0.76564306525459, 
0.733154511399898, 0.711372150025436, 0.687393053692827, 0.663367710308468, 
0.622716551819822, 0.599107431901216, 0.559889932016834, 0.539148129306757, 
0.511885492299866, 0.472413633630856, 0.417457055590967, 0.363316838551542, 
0.320700180363502, 0.396429727604865, 0.646441289367803, 0.666974980345003, 
0.63996670212274, 0.98566341395736, 1, 0.895620404199232, 0.784997456412154, 
0.717153031494242, 0.668940480044397, 0.623017157656199, 0.574504000369976, 
0.62199972251769), W2 = c(0.0460311814571106, 0.0471278676862886, 
0.0427411227695774, 0.0394807042504002, 0.0389471812199894, 0.0335823107475251, 
0.0341454739462921, 0.0315964194676625, 0.0264093900053353, 0.0205406366708164, 
0, 0.0034382595293141, 0.00856600865492908, 0.0167763352895845, 
0.0276246369079376, 0.0369909301084831, 0.040399549469441, 0.0331969885588949, 
0.034708637145059, 0.0393325034086195, 0.0308257750904024, 0.0095144940423261, 
0.012863833066572, 0.0253719841128698, 0.0363092062362914, 0.0453790977532753, 
0.0547453909538205, 0.0395992649238249, 0.026172268658486, 0.0294030470093069, 
0.0319817416562926, 0.0372280514553323, 0.0530559013575196, 0.0727666133143635, 
0.0940186140257278, 0.113284723457229, 0.131098464639279, 0.136907937637086, 
0.142924891813386, 0.142598849961468, 0.156648289762286, 0.169452842492145, 
0.182850198589128, 0.190796341114522, 0.203390835259944, 0.21237180627186, 
0.15522556168119, 0.142450649119687, 0.156381528247081, 0.153624992589958, 
0.848064497006343, 1, 0.957999881439327, 0.846286086904973, 0.782411524097457, 
0.742011974628016, 0.706147370917067, 0.662902365285435, 0.615122413895311
)), row.names = c(NA, 59L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What does K_1 equal to, the initial value? What is t_n - t_{n-1}? Time difference, in days?

Comment: t_n - t_{n-1} is time difference in days. The filter is initialized by setting Kt = 1 and W2(1) = W1(1).

Answer (score 1):

I optimized W2(t) iteratively using continuous optimization to find the value of T which minimizes W2(t) (if you want to maximize use a negative sign in front of your function). Code:

```
library(lubridate)
df$time_diff=c(NA,diff(as_datetime(df$Time)))
df$k=NA
df$k[1]=1
df$t=NA
df$W3=NA

myK=function(t){
  df$k[i-1]/(df$k[i-1]+exp(-df$time_diff[i]/t))
}

myW=function(t){
  df$W2[i-1]+myK(t)*(df$W1[i]-df$W2[i-1])
}

for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  tmp=optim(
    par=30,
    fn=myW,
    method="Brent",
    lower=1,
    upper=60
  )
  df$k[i]=myK(tmp$par)
  df$t[i]=tmp$par
  df$W3[i]=tmp$value
}
```

which results in

```
         Time          W1          W2 time_diff          k  t          W3
1  2017-01-01 0.026037090 0.046031181        NA 1.00000000 NA          NA
2  2017-01-02 0.024233455 0.047127868         1 0.73105857  1 0.030095767
3  2017-01-03 0.020626185 0.042741123         1 0.66524095  1 0.029497863
4  2017-01-04 0.020279332 0.039480704         1 0.64391425  1 0.028277656
5  2017-01-05 0.016417703 0.038947181         1 0.63640863  1 0.024803211
6  2017-01-06 0.011677381 0.033582311         1 0.63369131  1 0.021666546
7  2017-01-07 0.008231975 0.034145474         1 0.63269749  1 0.017543217
8  2017-01-08 0.003977246 0.031596419         1 0.63233267  1 0.015069118
9  2017-01-09 0.001156176 0.026409390         1 0.63219856  1 0.012352141
10 2017-01-10 0.000000000 0.020540637         1 0.63214924  1 0.009714714
11 2017-01-11 0.030869907 0.000000000         1 0.39127330 60 0.024582204
12 2017-01-12 0.091037321 0.003438260         1 0.28461524 60 0.025910609
13 2017-01-13 0.128821163 0.008566009         1 0.22444462 60 0.031579778
14 2017-01-14 0.157471211 0.016776335         1 0.18581144 60 0.036234298
15 2017-01-15 0.173727050 0.027624637         1 0.15891059 60 0.041717466
16 2017-01-16 0.158465523 0.036990930         1 0.13910460 60 0.045825205
17 2017-01-17 0.125052028 0.040399549         1 0.12391552 60 0.047903067
18 2017-01-18 0.101188549 0.033196989         1 0.11189902 60 0.047201779
19 2017-01-19 0.092933450 0.034708637         1 0.10215633 60 0.039299446
20 2017-01-20 0.078435000 0.039332503         1 0.09409885 60 0.038823238
21 2017-01-21 0.062734126 0.030825775         1 0.08732502 60 0.041376051
22 2017-01-22 0.058132544 0.009514494         1 0.08155147 60 0.033052682
23 2017-01-23 0.091777274 0.012863833         1 0.07657250 60 0.015813561
24 2017-01-24 0.125560746 0.025371984         1 0.07223521 60 0.021004518
25 2017-01-25 0.148268048 0.036309206         1 0.06842356 60 0.033780971
26 2017-01-26 0.143203996 0.045379098         1 0.06504790 60 0.043262488
27 2017-01-27 0.114785182 0.054745391         1 0.06203786 60 0.049684903
28 2017-01-28 0.089927392 0.039599265         1 0.05933746 60 0.056833001
29 2017-01-29 0.097974379 0.026172269         1 0.05690156 60 0.042920900
30 2017-01-30 0.121375387 0.029403047         1 0.05469342 60 0.031379253
31 2017-01-31 0.361212598 0.031981742         1 0.05268279 60 0.046883700
32 2017-02-01 0.835591731 0.037228051         1 0.05084455 60 0.072840926
33 2017-02-02 0.765643065 0.053055901         1 0.04915765 60 0.073035223
34 2017-02-03 0.733154511 0.072766613         1 0.04760436 60 0.085431563
35 2017-02-04 0.711372150 0.094018614         1 0.04616961 60 0.102250779
36 2017-02-05 0.687393054 0.113284723         1 0.04484049 60 0.120625812
37 2017-02-06 0.663367710 0.131098465         1 0.04360592 60 0.137271597
38 2017-02-07 0.622716552 0.136907938         1 0.04245631 60 0.151970756
39 2017-02-08 0.599107432 0.142924892         1 0.04138334 60 0.156035294
40 2017-02-09 0.559889932 0.142598850         1 0.04037971 60 0.159761818
41 2017-02-10 0.539148129 0.156648290         1 0.03943904 60 0.158238373
42 2017-02-11 0.511885492 0.169452842         1 0.03855571 60 0.170344712
43 2017-02-12 0.472413634 0.182850199         1 0.03772474 60 0.180881960
44 2017-02-13 0.417457056 0.190796341         1 0.03694172 60 0.191516979
45 2017-02-14 0.363316839 0.203390835         1 0.03620270 60 0.197042050
46 2017-02-15 0.320700180 0.212371806         1 0.03550419 60 0.207555808
47 2017-02-16 0.396429728 0.155225562         1 0.03484302 60 0.218784940
48 2017-02-17 0.646441289 0.142450649         1 0.03421637 60 0.172033179
49 2017-02-18 0.666974980 0.156381528         1 0.03362167 60 0.160086034
50 2017-02-19 0.639966702 0.153624993         1 0.03305663 60 0.172367225
51 2017-02-20 0.985663414 0.848064497         1 0.03251915 60 0.180682176
52 2017-02-21 1.000000000 1.000000000         1 0.03200733 60 0.852927548
53 2017-02-22 0.895620404 0.957999881         1 0.08004099  1 0.991645354
54 2017-02-23 0.784997456 0.846286087         1 0.17869466  1 0.927085272
55 2017-02-24 0.717153031 0.782411524         1 0.32693582  1 0.804067865
56 2017-02-25 0.668940480 0.742011975         1 0.47053632  1 0.729019277
57 2017-02-26 0.623017158 0.706147371         1 0.56122074  1 0.675229616
58 2017-02-27 0.574504000 0.662902365         1 0.60404760  1 0.626628509
59 2017-02-28 0.621999723 0.615122414         1 0.62149479  1 0.637481586
```

Alternatively if you want to brute force your way to a solution, for ex. by trying only a select number of T's, in the loop instead of optim you could do `myW(1:60)`, which would return solutions for all integers between 1 and 60, from these you can select your desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. T should be optimized using W1 and W2. I cannot see W1 and W2 being used in your code. Now how to calculate the equation one?

Comment: How to know the optimum value of T from the output?

Comment: @BappaDas it's in the column `t`, K is in column `k`, and your first formula is in `W3`.

Comment: @BappaDas Did this answer your question?

Comment: I am not sure as my approach was totally different from what you have provided.